# how to know the size of the components from gridlayout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

i have a jpanel with an unknown Dimension with gridlayout, and i want to know how to get the size information from components on it.

this is an example:

```
    JPanel basicInformation=new JPanel();
    basicInformation.setMaximumSize(100,100);
    basicInformation.setPreferredSize(basicInformation.getMaximumSize());
    basicInformation.setSize(basicInformation.getMaximumSize());
    basicInformation.setMinimumSize(basicInformation.getMaximumSize());
    basicInformation.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10));

    JLabel username=new JLabel("Example");
    username.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    username.setOpaque(true);
    basicInformation.add(username);
```

i want to know how to get the size of the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JLabel inherits [GetSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getSize%28%29) from Component which should return a Dimension for your use.

You can call this at any time, but if the frame or panel is not visible yet (i.e. still being constructed) it will return 0,0. Perform `getSize()` after any `.setVisible(true)` to get the correct value.

Comment: username.getSize().width or .height both returns 0.

Comment: Well that's no good. I'll look into it and get back to you on that.

Comment: I think I found out why. The frame has to be drawn before it gets a size. Set the frame to visible and then try to fetch it. I tried before and after setting the frame to visible and when not visible, it returned 0,0, and when visible, it returned proper HW

Comment: it is possible to get it before it's visible? right now im using a getSize() from the panel, like this:

username.setSize(new Dimension(basicInformation.getSize()- marginY,basicInformation.getSize()- marginX));

Comment: From what I can tell, no. You could try setting it visible and hiding it again after that to get the size if you wished. Alternatively, you could create a resize method that occurs after everything is drawn to set the username's size.

Answer (score 0):

```
username.getPreferredSize();
```

Returns the Dimension.

```
username.getPreferredSize().width; 
username.getPreferredSize().height;
```

Returns the individual components.